# how to track outlook email content to trigger event in linux server

Tags: linux, outlook, outlook-restapi

let me know your views or thoughts on it or you can guide me to correct directions.

I thought of couple of options myself to automate Linux User expiry renewal process where we need project manager approval on emails. Not sure if its possible but i want to automate it and save our time.

So, read email message body for "Approved" and "Project Name" keyword which when receive will trigger a event and send data to linux server which in turn renew the linux user.

So how to establish communication between Outlook email and Linux server via event ?

Comment: There are a lot of unclear things - where the email is received, whether a user should open that email or not and etc.

Comment: @Sushil.R - Could please provide some more details around the scenario you are trying to automate?

Comment: Thank you both of  you for taking time and replying back. here is what is the what i am thinking to achieve

Scenario: 

when we will get outlook email with keyword in its mail body "Approved" it should trigger a event which can then go to the Linux server and trigger a script to auto renew the user.